# Looping on login screen after installing new amd driver

Tags: 14.04

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and have it AMD driver installed. When it rebooted, it kept back to login screen even my password is correct. What is wrong? Do I have to reinstall the Ubuntu?

Actually I run it on Virtualbox

Comment: Don't install graphics drivers in Virtuabox. The virtualized Grpahics adapter is NOT the same as the real one running the host OS. You need to install the Guest Additions according to the guest OS.

Comment: Thank you! i finally install it in harddisk and it works!

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have selected your Video output correctly and enabled 3d Hardware acceleration. Without that, I think it won't work properly. Also, try increasing your video memory for the OS in Virtualbox.